# CalledFromWrongThreadException - But thread was started in standard fashion inside jar/lib

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to Android but am experienced in programming Java.
I've got a non-open-source library which I want to include in a simple Android One-Click-Test-Program.
My problem is, that the constructor starts a thread in Java standard fashion 
`new Thread(new Runnable ... ).start` etc.
but this causes a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` in Android (MainActivity).

Is there any way to push it into the RightThread?

Comment: plz show relevant part of code to get more help from us

Comment: the Thread is created inside the jar which I cannot modify. I just instantiate it with `HiddenClass myInstance = new HiddenClass(some, args)` In standard Java it returns immediately but continues doing some extensive work in background.

Comment: The background thread probably communicates back to your app at some point, right? Based on the exception, it sounds like you're attempting to manipulate something in that callback( or somwhere further down the chain of calls) that should really be happing on the main/UI thread. Use @MaciejGórski's answer to force that logic runs on the UI thread.

Comment: YEAAHHHH !!! Thank you very much! This is the right hint! Now I've got the anchor and will be back as soon I've understood what's really happened. Yes, it was one argument pointing back to a member of the UIThread.

Answer (score 0):

`CalledFromWrongThreadException` is usunally thrown when you try to modify UI from another thread. If that's what happens in your closed-source library, then you can just bin it. If it is in your code, you have many options: [`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or using `Handler` for safe thread communication.

Comment: I've already tried runOnUiThread but to no avail. Same issue. And no, the library does not know anything about Android or its UI.

Comment: Once again, `SomeClass myInstance = new SomeClass(some, args)` crashes if the SomeClass-Constructor starts its own Thread in Java standard fashion. This is the intrinsic problem.

Comment: @Carsten That doesn't help. How about full stack trace?

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your support. I think I've found the reason. See my comment @MH above.